# How to prevent unwanted update of persisted objects?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a `Load` class and a `Cargo` class.  An instance of `Load` contains an instance of `Cargo`.

```
class Load {
    Cargo cargo
}

class Cargo {
    String name
    BigDecimal cost
}
```

Lets say that the `name` of an instance of `Cargo` is "rock" and the `cost` is "11.11".  Now I use this instance of `Cargo` to create an instance of `Load`.  Now that the instance of `Load` has been created I don't want it's "cargo" to change.  For instance, if I change the price of "rock" to "22.22" I don't want the price of the "cargo" in my instance of `Load` to change.  What is the optimal way to handle such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you can only have one *Cargo* per *Load* (as per your example), you'll want to add a `cost` property to *Load*.  Then you will need to copy over the cost at the time the objects are created.  You might be able to do this via an overloaded method in the Load object, or just write your own method to add *Cargo* to *Load*.

If you actually need multiple *Cargoes* per *Load*, then you'll want an intermediate object to represent the connection.  This object will store the price at the time they were associated.  That might look like:

```
class Load {
    LoadCargo loadCargo
}
class LoadCargo {
    Cargo cargo
    BigDecimal cost
}
class Cargo {
    String name
    BigDecimal cost
}
```

Of course, your object model will be a bit more complicated, because of the indirect relationship to Cargo.

*Edit*
Another way to handle the multiple-related situation is to duplicate the *Cargo* every time the cost is updated.  This might be more efficient if you are expecting `cost` to be mostly static.  I'd handle this by adding a field to "disable" items, like so:

```
class Cargo {
    String name
    BigDecimal cost
    boolean active = true
}
```

I believe you can simply clone the Cargo on update like this:

```
oldCargo = Cargo.get(params.id)
newCargo = new Cargo()
newCargo.properties = oldCargo.properties
// now set the new cost, etc.
newCargo.save()
oldCargo.active = false
oldCargo.save()
```

That's just a guess, it probably is broken.

Comment: Humm, I was afraid that creating another object was going to be how this was done. I have several questions regarding that, but the most important one is, will that not make the DB huge (too huge)?

Comment: It shouldn't, unless you are storing billions of transactions.  It's only two ids and an extra numeric field.  It's not a ton of data.  Either way, you absolutely *have* to store the original value, or you *have* to duplicate the Cargo every time it is updated.  (That's another way to do it... Let me update the answer.)

Comment: Well, my classes is more complex than what I posted, I was just giving an example of my problem.  In my Load class alone, I have eight fields which represent instance of other objects, and those other objects have fields which represent instance of other objects and so on. I don't expect to ever have a billion transactions, but maybe into the tens of thousands some day.  I was hoping Grails had an easy (well, easier) way to take care of this, and from what I have seen of Grails so far I expect there is, I am probably just missing something :)

Comment: The issue is, no matter what Grails or a plugin does, behind the scenes either the Cargo object is being duplicated, or you are storing the static information twice.  There's no way around it!  (I once found an unfinished plugin to do something similar to my last example, but I can't find it again.)

Comment: Ok, moving forward with this, is `active` in `oldCargo.active = false` just a boolean that I would add to the `Cargo` domain to indicate if an instance `Cargo` was "active" or not? Also, what exactly are you filtering with `filter{ k,v -> k != 'id' }`?

Comment: `active` is there so you can filter out the "old" versions of Cargo.  Basically, you'll be cloning it, so you'll have to run your queries in such a way to remove duplicates.  The filter might not be necessary - I've seen other examples where they just did `a.properties = b.properties; a.save()`  I don't know for sure if that will work, but you should try it first.  Actually, that filter code is probably a bad idea - I think I'm going to edit it out of the answer.

Comment: Ok, I have been working with this and I see a few issues. First, creating a new instance of `Cargo` on an update will also create a new `id` number for that instance, making it difficult to look up loads by what cargo was hauled.  Another issues along the same lines is, since creating a new instance of `Cargo` on update causes a new `id` number to be generated, it will make it difficult for users to keep track of what `id` number belongs to what cargo. For instance a cargo called "Dirt" might be id # 7, but when the price changed the id # would also change. This just seems messy, any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't use database IDs in this case.  Or just copy the price, like originally stated.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but thus far the solutions present all have some issue. If I just copy the price like you said, then I will not be able to do things like generate a report listing all instance of `Load` with a certain cargo. I would in that case still have to have a reference to an instance of `Cargo`, which isn't that big of a deal, but I just want to make it as clean, efficient, and easy to follow as possible

Comment: Programming is all about compromises.  That's life!