# Grails: Collection in domain object without hasMany

Tags: grails

I have two domain objects A and B.

A can be associated with many Bs but I do not want any save cascade from A to B.

I'm thinking of defining the hasMany relationship form A to B, but then setting a cascade behavior.  Any ideas?

This is an example of my domain objects:

class A{

static hasMany = [bees:B]
}

class B{
}

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish for GORM to manage the save/updates for your collection simply don't use hasMany. Instead treat it as a simple HashSet property.

Comment: Hm, I tried this but it did not work.  I putting a "Set<B> bees" property in domain object A, but this did nothing.  Grails doesn't seem to know what the Set contains and could not create a mapping table for it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use 'belongsTo' on B, and don't declare anything on A?  This way you'll get the foreign key to 'A', but operations on 'A' won't affect 'B'.  You lose a bit of convenience, but can still easily look up all 'B' by 'A'.  I actually prefer this because I don't need to worry about lazy loading gotchas and hibernate going and loading all the 'B's when I'm just trying to add one (assuming you don't need that functionality).

```
class A{}

class B{
  static belongsTo = [your_a:A]
 }

 //get your B's for a given A
  B.findAllByA(your_A_instance, ...paging, etc...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own cascading behavior in the `static mappings` block of your Domain class.

See here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html

Comment: That I know, but the problem is there is no option to say cascade: 'none'.  This behavior is what I'm looking for, a hasMany association, but absolutely no cascades.

Comment: Have you tried the value 'none'? Hibernate docs seem to say there is a 'none' option and if Grails is a layer over Hibernate it might pass through.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying what I think your are saying then what you are talking about is not cascading. A simple outline of your classes would be helpful. If you have an instance of `A` which is associated with many instances of `B`, then all instance of `B` which reference the instance of `A` in question are referencing *the exact same object*.  I had the same problem and asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279185/how-to-prevent-unwanted-update-of-persisted-objects).  Basically your options are:

1.) Clone the instance of `A` whenever it changes or whenever you deem appropriate.

2.) Create new fields in your `B` class which will hold the values of `A` you are concerned with.

Both approaches have their advantages and disadvantages, but for me option 2 proved to be the better choice.