# grails hasOne vs hasMany behavior

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In grails, when specifying a unidirectional one-to-one relationship, I can do either

```
class MyDomainClass {
   AnotherDomainClass another
}
```

or

```
class MyDomainClass {
   static hasOne = [another:AnotherDomainClass]
}
```

I know the semantics are different, but either way will establish this relationship.

When creating a hasMany relationship, I can do:

```
class MyDomainClass {
  static hasMany = [others:AnotherDomainClass]
}
```

But I can't seem to do:

```
class MyDomainClass {
  List<AnotherDomainClass> others 
}
```

Edit: Clarification. I would like to still have the hasMany relationship, I'm just wondering if it's possible to do so just by declaring `List<AnotherDomainClass> others` without the `hasMany` variable. I was hoping that just declaring `List<AnotherDomainClass>` would create a join table automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do. Just declare both.

```
class MyDomainClass {

  List<AnotherDomainClass> others 

  static hasMany = [others:AnotherDomainClass]

}
```

When you not declare the field, Grails automatically create a `Set` for you.

Comment: I guess what I should have asked is it possible to do just `List<AnotherDomainClass> others` without the `hasMany`

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe what you need is answered in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705116/grails-collection-in-domain-object-without-hasmany) (look at belongsTo) ?

Comment: You can add a list to the domain class and not have it be used in creation/saving/updating of tables by saying `static List<AnotherDomainClass> others`

Comment: I think I might be being a little unclear (and overcomplicating things). I added a clarification to the question.